# StaticResource or bug in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am getting:

**'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '244' and line position '11'.** and I totally understand that it is due to missing StaticResource or even mistype or case sensitive situations but I have checked each case that could be the issue yet I don't see any problem in my tagging or code.  Could be a bug or still there are other cases that I'm not family with?  I will appreciate your advice.

Thank you

Comment: I was getting those errors today and the position was misleading, it turned out to be further down in the templated style/control template.

Comment: This is the tag in XAML `code`   <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
                <Expander Header="Controls" Content="{StaticResource FCS}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsExpanded="True" />
        </DockPanel>

Comment: I cannot believe it ... I noticed its key had received a space from nowhere!!! so it was x:key="  FCS" by changing it to x:key="FCS" it started to work.  I hope Microsoft would come up with a different way of defining key.  Thanks to all

Comment: @amitkohan - use "View White Space" (CTRL+E,S) option in VS. It will add dots where spaces are (and arrows for tabs). If you see a dot inside quote marks (and it isn't a string) - there's a problem. It takes some time to get used to it. But when you're used to them, these dots that are misplaced pop out at you. Saves a lot of time.